# How the Xcode scheme menu/popupButton implemented?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, appkit

On Xcode's toolbar, it has a scheme selection menu (or like a NSPopupButton). It looks like was implemented with two NSPopupButton. Or implemented with two buttons, each with a menu. Anyone has suggestion on how to implement this?

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: As someone who's not a fan of that control, and who has seen the usability and discoverability problems that it has caused (many, many people don't know that that button has two different menus), I would advise not imitating it.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode's Scheme menu uses a path control (NSPathControl), which Xcode also uses for its jump bars. The path control is in Xcode's Object Library so adding one to your application is relatively easy. Getting the path control to look and behave like the Scheme menu would require more work.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't thought about the path control. I will try it out. Thanks for the help!